# How to serialize a singleton object?

Tags: java, serialization

I'm implementing some kind of AdressBook and wanna save all the contacts in some kind of DB implemented by myself as a singleton `HashMap<String, Contact> contactsDB`. Is it possible to serialize such an object?

Comment: @Jak: Yes, Ruby documentation helps here.

Comment: Removed... My mistake...:( oops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is some stuff

```
// assume that the signleton is actually implemented correctly.
public class IHateSingletons
{
  Map<String, Contact> contactMap;

  public void storeThatStuffs(final ObjectOutputStream outputStream)
  {
    outputStream.writeObject(contactMap);
  }

  public void readThatStuffs(final ObjectInputStream inputStream)
  {
    contactMap = (Map<String, Contact>)inputStream.readObject();
}
```

Comment: A large number of contacts (as in, too many to fit in memory) will indicate that this implementation (hooty singleton) is a terrible choice.  In that case, use a real database.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware, that if you do this, you're providing a way for to circumnavigate the singleton-ness of your class (the code no longer has to via the getObject method which makes sure there is only one object created, it can no, seperately, de-serialize a serialized object to).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the java [serializable](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) API. If your custom class implements 'serializable' i think you're fine

Answer (score 0):

Dont serialize the singleton itself, serialize the underlying data on which the singleton acts.

Comment: And what if i have over 100/1000/10000 contacs, deserialize each into the HashMap? Isn't it too much for the cpu and memory?

Comment: If a contact is a person with contact details, 10000 contacts will not use a great amount of memory / cpu / storage space, unless you are using a mobile device with limited resources...

Comment: If each contact uses 256 bytes, you can store 4 million of these in 1 GB.  If you buy a 16 GB machine for $1000, it can store 40+ million contacts using a plain HashMap.  If you want to store 50 million to 5 billion, I have a different solution for that. ;)